# how to locally store data from WebService in ios 9 using swift

Tags: swift2

I am using AlamoFire webService in our project, then if connect Internet automatically store webservice data to Local storage data, check the internet connection if true then connect webservice otherwise show local storage data in our app

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C code:

NSUserDefault or CoreData used to locally stored the data from WebService. i have create the custom class NSUserDefault,

- (void)HomeScreenGetvalue: (NSArray *)value : (NSString *)key {

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:value forKey:key];

  [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

  NSLog(@"logggg %@",value);
  }
- (NSArray *)HomeScreenSetvalue: (NSString *)key {

  NSArray *savedValue = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                          arrayForKey:key];

  NSLog(@"savevale %@",savedValue);

  return savedValue;
  }

Then I have used the NSUserDefault in WebService using AFNetWorking 2.4,

LocalUserDefaults *userDe = [[LocalUserDefaults alloc]init];

```
if (![self connected]) {

    movies = [userDe HomeScreenSetvalue:@"homekeyvalues"].mutableCopy; 

    [_mytableView reloadData];

} else {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://////?"];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        //movies are NSMutableArray value

        movies = [responseObject objectForKey:@"enquiry"];

        NSSortDescriptor *titleSort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"FirstName"
                                                                  ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];

        movies=[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[movies sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[titleSort]]];

        NSLog(@"The Array: %@",movies);

        **[userDe HomeScreenGetvalue:movies :@"homekeyvalues"];**

        [self.mytableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Request Failed: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);

    }];

    [operation start];
}
```

Its Working for me.......